# JavaScript HTML5 Canvas Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a simple animation using HTML5 and JavaScript. I would like to use the practices shown in my original code where the JS file and html file are separate however the animation does not seem to show up in any browser. Why?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http=equiv-"content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>My Animation</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="450" width="450">
        <p>Canvas not supported</p>
    </canvas>

    <script src="myAnimation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**myAnimation.js**

```
window.addEventListener('load', drawCircle);
drawCircle();

function drawCircle() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
  context = canvas.getcontext("2d"),
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // color in the background
  context.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // draw the circle
  context.beginPath();

  context.arc(225, 225, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.closePath();

  // color in the circle
  context.fillStyle = "#006699";
  context.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code you've posted:

1) It should be `canvas.getContext` not `canvas.getcontext` (the camelCase is important).

2) `radius` is undefined.

[Here's what's displayed when I've made those changes](http://jsfiddle.net/2rjw6b39/3/).

[And here's what happens when I randomise `radius` at the top of the function!](http://jsfiddle.net/2rjw6b39/4/)

Groovy.

Comment: And canvas, context should been declared using var (not essential in this case to function though). Nice effect too! :)

Answer (score 1):

you didn't defined `radius` and misspelled `getContext`

check out this tools - might be helpful:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

or

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger